# Deep cycle battery charging

Tags: batteries

I'm building a project, installing solar powered air conditioners in six separate rooms, all with  separate battery banks. How can I get a battery charger that could charge the batteries with time since the air conditioners are only solar panel charged and not inverters?

Comment: Are you talking about something like [this](http://www.harvest.cn/solarac.asp?gclid=COD47-_fj7ICFaMQNAodrTEAzg)? What exactly do you want to do that isn't shown here?

Comment: The language in your question is unclear. "Charge the batteries with time" doesn't tell me anything. Nor does "only solar panel charged and not inverters".

Answer (score 1):

@dike are you referring to that the AC units are directly connected to the solar panels and do not have electrical plugs on them and then connected to the panels? If so then research solar panel power adapters. And by time the correct term is **trickle charge**.